# Сортировка JSON в PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть Json, нужно отсортировать по num.

```
$str = '{
    "cb":[
        {
            "name":"cb",
            "num":0
        },
        {
            "name":"cb2",
            "num":7
        },
        {
            "name":"cbRed",
            "num":3
        }
    ]
} ';
$data = json_decode($str, true);
usort($data, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a->cb->num < $b->cb->num ? -1 : 1;
});                                                                                                                                                                                                        

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в своем коде вы делаете несколько ошибок. Во-первых, вам надо отсортировать `$data['cb']`, а вы сортируете сам массив `$data`.
Во-вторых, вы десериализуете json  в массив, а в сортировке обращатесь к нему как к объекту, а не массиву.

Так что ваш код следует исправить следующим образом

```
usort($data['cb'], function($a, $b) {.
    return $a['num'] - $b['num'];
});.
```

что касается возврата значения из функции-компаратора, то не обязательно возвращать `-1/1`. достаточно вернуть отрицательно/положительное значение. Так что проще всего вернуть разность значений. В пхп7 также был введен оператор `<=>`